# Android Autocomplete text view with filter

Tags: android, delay, freeze, autocompletetextview

I am using an autocomplete textview to filter by any letter. 
The concept is working, but when I enter each letter, the application freezes or having a delay for some time.
 Also while deleting too, the same happens. What am I doing wrong? is there anything am missing? My adapter class is added below.
Thanks in Advance.

```
public class ListAccNoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListAccNo> {

Context context;
int resource, textViewResourceId;
List<ListAccNo> items, tempItems, suggestions;

public ListAccNoAdapter(Context context, int resource, int 
 textViewResourceId, List<ListAccNo> items) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.items = items;
    tempItems = new ArrayList<ListAccNo>(items); // this makes the 
     difference.
    suggestions = new ArrayList<ListAccNo>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    }
    ListAccNo accnum = items.get(position);
    if (accnum != null) {
        TextView lblName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_name);
        if (lblName != null)
            lblName.setText(accnum.getName());
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}
/**
 * Custom Filter implementation for custom suggestions we provide.
 */
Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        String str = ((ListAccNo) resultValue).getName();
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {

            List<ListAccNo> suggestions = new ArrayList<ListAccNo>();
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            for (ListAccNo accno : tempItems) {
                if (accno.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {                

                    suggestions.add(accno);
                }
            }

            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();


            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults 
    results) {
        List<ListAccNo> filterList = (ArrayList<ListAccNo>) 
   results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (ListAccNo accnum : filterList) {
                add(accnum);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    } 
};
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use your solution, but I get an UnsupportedOperationException when calling clear() in publishResults. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. 
While setting the adapter in MainActivity, i have given a step to

```
autotextview.setThreshold(1);
```

Removing this line of code solved the issue.

Thanks Everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have used the AutoCompleteTextView and its working fine.
I have put the contents to be rendered in AutoCompleteTextView in String array first.
Then I've set the adapter contents in AutoCompleteTextView.

```
 String[] arr=["a","b","c","d"]; // array contents
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> 
       (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arr);
 AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView= 
       (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
 autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
 autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I am using a custom textview. Using adapter class. normal AutoCompleteTextview is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults 
results) {
    List<ListAccNo> filterList = (ArrayList<ListAccNo>) 


 results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (ListAccNo accnum : filterList) {
                add(accnum);
           //remove from here     notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
// put here  notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } 
    };
```

Check your code, you are `notifyDataSetChanged` inside the loop, i think it will notify for each and every item thats why getting freezing, can you please check to remove this from inside loop and notify after completion of loop.I think it will work.